# jsonapi.org nested resources

Tags: json, rest

Is it legal to have a nested resources in a jsonapi.org compliant REST web service?

If you look at the JSON below, I'd like to return a list of clubs (type=club), and at the same time, a list of members for each club (type=member).

In this case, the member resource is actually what I'm querying for, but the service will return a list of members for multiple clubs.

What is the best/proper way to structure that?

```
{
    ...
    "data" : [
        {
            "id":1,
            "type": "club",
            "attributes":{
                ...
                "members":[
                    {
                        "id":"101",
                        "type": "member",
                        "attributes":{
                            "memberType":"president",
                            "memberSince":"2015-01-01"
                        }
                    }
                ]
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

Comment: It looks like http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents should give you what you need. If I read the API spec right, it specifically prohibits including the data of included members in the main `attributes` field. Instead, you reference those members in the `relationships` field by type/id, and then include the actual data payload in the `included` field.